# Omega theme not rendering correctly when css aggregation is disabled

Tags: css-js-aggregation

I have tried clearing the drupal caches and manually deleting the aggregated files. Also tried clearing the browser cache.

Anyone seen this problem before?

Answer (score 1):

Can be because it needs polyfills which are only loaded with aggregation turned on.

Try with a CSS3 standards compliant browser (ie. latest version of Chrome) which would not need the polyfills at all.

Omega 4 comes with these polyfills:

- Selectivizr.js
- CSS3 Media Queries JS
- Respond.js
- CSS3 PIE
- HTML5 shiv